# The current path, accounts/signUp/signUp, didn't match any of these

Tags: python, html, django, postgresql

hello im facing an issue when trying to make a sign up page in django

when i submit in the html form a user should be created in the database but its not happening and it shows this message

"The current path, accounts/signUp/signUp, didn't match any of these"
and this in the terminal
"Not Found: /accounts/signUp/signUp"

**views.py:**

```
from django.shortcuts import render,redirect
from django.contrib.auth.models import User,auth
# Create your views here.


def signUp(request):

    if request.method=='post':
        first_name=request.POST['first_name']
        last_name=request.POST['last_name']
        username=request.POST['username']
        password1=request.POST['password1']
        rePassword=request.POST['repassword']
        email=request.POST['email']

        user = User.objects.create_user(username=username,password=password1,email=email,first_name=first_name,last_name=last_name)
        user.save();
    
    else:    
        return render(request,'signUp.html')
```

**signUp.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Sign Up</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="signUp" method="post">
        {% csrf_token%}

        <input type="text" name="first_name" placeholder="First Name"><br>
        <input type="text" name="last_name" placeholder="Last Name"><br>
        <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Username"><br>
        <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="email"><br>
        <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password"><br>
        <input type="password" name="rePassword" placeholder="Confirm Password"><br>
        <input type="submit">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The error is from your urls (or routers if you have used them). Please chase that too

Answer (score 1):

`form action="signUp"`

This will not do anything when the form is submitted.

You need to change that to your `signUp` url.

So if your url is `path('signup/', views.signUp, name='signUp')`

**You would use: `form action="{% url 'signUp' %}`**

Another thing is your view doesn't seem to present any success message for sign up when handling `POST`, you may want to redirect them to another page or include a success message.